# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express : Login failed for user

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have an application in C#2010, a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, I don't have any problem to connect to my database `MyDB` on my work PC where I developed the application. But when I tried to install it on an other PC, and after configure my sever like this :

```
USE [master] 
GO 

CREATE LOGIN [User1] WITH PASSWORD=N'Pass', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=ON 
GO 

EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'User1', @rolename = N'sysadmin' 
GO 

EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2 
GO

RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] FROM DISK = N'pathtoMyDB\MyDB.bak' WITH FILE = 1,
NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10 
GO
```

I run the application, here my problem : when I try to connect to MyDB, I get this message :

> *Login failed for user 'WIN-ELKPAS5MS2O\User1'. Reason: Failed to open
>   the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]*

Comment: Yes I created a user to this login, but the error is still occured, when I run the SQLcmd, I read : DataBase MyDB not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created a **login** - that's fine, but that's on the **server** (instance) level. The login gives this account/user rights to connect to the server - that's just step 1, though.

Now you're restoring a database - but you're not creating a **user** inside that database that corresponds to that login you've just created.

So after the `RESTORE DATABASE`, you also need:

```
USE MyDB
GO

CREATE USER User1 FOR LOGIN User1;
GO
```

**Now** you have a user inside your freshly restored database that corresponds to that login - and now, hopefully, your application will work.

Comment: I tried to excute your commande, but I get this message :
DataBase 'MyDB' not found

Comment: Ok, so why do you not start a question "I dont know how to name a database?". If MyDB does not exist, is is not obvious that you can not connect to it?

Comment: TomTom : When i excute the restore commande, I can find the database in SqlServer folder, but when I excute this comande : Use [MyDB], I get: Database not found !!

Comment: 'to a different instance', please explain it

Comment: @aEkBKF: you can have multiple **instances** (versions/copies) of SQL Server on the same machine - one SQL Server 2008, another SQL Server 2012 etc. - those are called **instances** and have a name (e.g. `SQLEXPRESS` for SQL Server Express etc.)

Comment: No, I have just one instance, SQLSever 2008 R2 Express

Comment: I found the solution; I didn't add a user to Login, and I didn't write the correct DataBase name, I wrote MyBD, but the correct one is MyDB
Thank you all